# Outer Container div not expanding vertically automatically... why?

Tags: html, css

Ok, i thought of starting afresh following some confusions in my previous similiar post. Here, I am trying to know the exact "reason" as to why exactly my outer container div ("container" , pink) is not automatically expanding vertically to fit the content div ("content" , red) (which automatically expands vertically with length of text). I am looking a reason more than the solution, because the reason will help me understand the concept more deeply. Please copy dummy text loremipsum... several times in the "content" div so that it overflows from page

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXIXy.jpg)

here is the code:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 100%;
}



.container {
width: 600px;
left: 0px;
position: relative;
right: 0px;
background-color: rgba(216,86,112,0.5);
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
}

.content {
height: auto;
width: 200px;
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: auto;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
margin: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
/* Paste dummy text here more than a page */
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

Instead of using

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
 }
```

try:

```
.container {
  height: auto;
 }
```

and instead of

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
 }
```

use

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
 }
```

**Here's why**

> When an element is set to be 'position: absolute' it wont collapse with any other element, that's why your container doesn't expand at all.
>
> When an element is set to be 'Height:100%' it takes the height of its container, in your case the cointainer is the **body** which means it will take 100% percent of your screen (in your case), but your content is way higher than the screen and that's why it overflows your content.

Hope you understand....